# How to define $0\cdot\infty$ in Lebesgue's integral?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider zero function on $\mathbb{R}$. If we use Lebesgue integral this will be $0\cdot\infty$. How is it defined? In analysis, we have to work it out with infinitesimals, so it is not necessarily zero.

Also on the other hand, if we integrate infinity on a null set the result is also zero. But what if I integrate Dirac function / Dirac comb?

Comment: use the Lebesgue integral for  non-negative functions, which uses $0\cdot \infty = 0$, same argument for if you're integrating the function that is infinity on a null set

Comment: What if $\int \Sigma_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(x+n) \text{d}\mu$?

Comment: what is delta? a measure? Do you have two measures there?

Comment: Dirac delta function.

Comment: You say that as if its a function. Not a well formed expression

Comment: The integral as you wrote it makes no sense. If you asked about $\int_{\mathbb R}\sum\selta(x-n)$ _that_ integral is  $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}1=\infty$. Has nothing to do with $0\cdot\infty$ as far as I can see.

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta(x+n)$ the same as $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(x)$?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Shashi No,  it's not the same as that at all. Yes you're missing something.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My thoughts were: for some given value $x$ there can only be one value of $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for which $x+n=0$ hence the series is either $0$ or $1$ depending whether $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich never mind, I already see what is wrong... It is not the $\delta$-measure, but the $\delta$-function.

Answer (score 1):

I think we define this quantity, for any set of infinite measure, to be $0$ (and I just consulted Bass's *Real Analysis for Graduate Students*, Ch.6, which agrees with me). This is convenient because we want examples like yours to come out to $0$.

Comment: So it is a definition? Should not be proved?

Comment: @CO2 Bass presents it as a "convention." So, yes.

Comment: As we discussed above: integral of "infinity on a null set". But what if I integrate the Dirac comb?

Comment: The Dirac comb is itself a measure. You don't have a proper expression to make sense out of.

Comment: Isn't measure defined on the simga algebra? But this comb is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Well, maybe I should ask what is the real definition of the Dirac function?

Comment: @CO2 That's a different question -- it's certainly not a well defined function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Calvin Khor has alluded to the fact that the signature property of the Dirac function -- that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)$ -- could be interpreted as an integral over a Dirac _measure_. Perhaps Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#As_a_measure) would be a good place to start looking at how this works rigorously.

Answer (score 0):

use the Lebesgue integral for non-negative functions, which uses $0⋅∞=0$ as a convention, same argument for if you're integrating the function that is infinity on a null set.

It is not correct to have two measures in an integral,
$$  \int_{\mathbb R} \sum_n \delta (x+n) d\mu=?$$

If you were instead computing
$$  \int_{\mathbb R} \sum_n \delta (x+n) dx$$
then [the $dx$ is just a notation, and] you should note that the null sets with respect to the Dirac comb measure are the sets that avoid the integers.

---

The dirac function is the measure given by
$$ \int_U \delta (x) dx = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \in U \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
To define the dirac comb from this, you will also need to define translations of measures, addition of measures, and some appropriate space to take an infinite sum in. Alternatively you can just define it as the measure
$$\int_U \sum_n \delta (x+n)dx = | \mathbb Z \cap U|$$

Comment: Ahh, ok, now I more or less understand. So both of these two cases are conventions? Actually, I study engineering.. So we were told Dirac "function" and using some sloopy sequence to approach it, so I thought it was really a function..

Comment: Yeah, the $0\cdot\infty = 0 $ is one of the starting conventions from which you build the rest of the theory for the non-negative lebesgue integral.

Comment: How do we define a $\infty-\infty$? In the $L^1$ space, if we encounter such kind of cases, then it is not a vector space any more?

Comment: But how can you find this case if you stay in $L^1$?

Comment: The two functions take infinity at some points but they have finite absolute integral.

Comment: This behavior can only be on a null set so just choose $\infty - \infty = 42$ if you want.

Comment: Wait.. But I don't think you can define it too arbitrarily. E.g. $f(0)=\infty$, $g(0)=1$. Then $f-(f+g)=-g$ but it is still "infinity minus infinity".

Comment: First of all you can't be using the dirac measure, as then $\{0\}$ is very far from being a null set. So lets pretend its the standard Lebesgue measure. Then its fine as long as you consider $f $ and $g$ to be elements of $L^1$, which are only defined almost everywhere. In fact for such 'functions', $f(0)$ doesn't make sense. However, $f - (f+g) = g$ almost everywhere, and that is all the lebesgue integral can see.

Comment: sorry, $(f+g) - f = g$.